# Consistent Line Spacing in Customized Titles

Tags: spacing, formatting, chapters, line-spacing

I find when I produce titles I get line spacing that depends on whether I have a hanging character ie `qypg` which dip below the usual base line vs `wertuioasdfhklzxcvbnm` which don't.  This is particularly visible when I use lines or super large fonts i.e. on a main title page.

Is there a way to make a consistent spacing that doesn't add the specified spacing at the bottom of a character?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp,textgreek,mathspec}
\usepackage{xpatch}  % can exclude etoolbox. xpatch loads it anyway, since egreg (xpatch author) extends etoolbox

\makeatletter
%http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html

\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vskip 20\p@
    }}
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
        {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
            \thickhrulefill
            \par\nobreak
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \hrule
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            \Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
            \par
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \hrule
            \vskip 20\p@
        }}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{A title with a hanging character}

    Please note and compare to the next chapter, the relative line spacing between the Chapter title and the lower hline placement.  

    \chapter{All above line characters}

    This line doesn't have enough space after it, I believe this is because of the characters that dip below the regular virtual alignment line

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not be loading that mix of packages. If you are using Lua/XeTeX, then you should not be using `textgreek` or `textcomp`. If you are using (pdf)TeX, then you should not try to load `mathspec`.

Comment: @cfr Uh-oh.  I think I will open a new question citing your comment here to give a better forum for a detailed answer.  I use `XeTeX` but prefer to avoid inserting symbols and special characters as my text container can't save them, and these packages have been crucial to me and using non-math-mode greek text that doesn't show up in math mode type italics.  The only problem I ever had was with `\textgamma` but I wasn't convinced this was a symptom of a larger problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\strut`:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp,textgreek,mathspec}
\usepackage{xpatch}  % can exclude etoolbox. xpatch loads it anyway, since egreg (xpatch author) extends etoolbox

\makeatletter
%http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html

\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \Large \bfseries \strut#1\strut\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vskip 20\p@
    }}
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
        {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
            \thickhrulefill
            \par\nobreak
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \hrule
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            \Large \bfseries \strut#1\strut\par\nobreak
            \par
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \hrule
            \vskip 20\p@
        }}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{A title with a hanging character}

    Please note and compare to the next chapter, the relative line spacing between the Chapter title and the lower hline placement.  

    \chapter{All above line characters}

    This line doesn't have enough space after it, I believe this is because of the characters that dip below the regular virtual alignment line

\end{document}
```

If, on the other side, you'd like to have zero depth, you can place the tiles in a `\smash`ed (with `b` option) `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp,textgreek,mathspec}
\usepackage{xpatch}  % can exclude etoolbox. xpatch loads it anyway, since egreg (xpatch author) extends etoolbox

\makeatletter
%http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html

\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \Large\bfseries\smash[b]{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering#1}}\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vskip 20\p@
    }}
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
        {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
            \thickhrulefill
            \par\nobreak
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \hrule
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            \Large\bfseries\smash[b]{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering#1}}\par\nobreak
            \par
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \hrule
            \vskip 20\p@
        }}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{A title with a hanging character}

    Please note and compare to the next chapter, the relative line spacing between the Chapter title and the lower hline placement.  

    \chapter{All above line characters}

    This line doesn't have enough space after it, I believe this is because of the characters that dip below the regular virtual alignment line

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Personally, I'd suggest you the first option, with some adjustment to the bottom rule, possibly.

### Remarks

1. A `\strut` is basically a zero width rule whose total height (height+depth) equals `\baselineskip`. The definitions in the kernel:

   ```
   \newbox\strutbox
   \def\strut{\relax\ifmmode\copy\strutbox\else\unhcopy\strutbox\fi}

   \setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
     \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
     \@depth.3\baselineskip
     \@width\z@}
   ```

   so if you find that a standard `\strut` is not enough for your purposes, you could easily define your own variant of `\strut`.
2. See [`cfr's comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254934/consistent-line-spacing/254936#comment609646_254934) regarding some of the packages loaded.

Comment: You beat me to the `\strut` answer by ten seconds! You want to add a sentence or two about how the OP might go about creating his/her own struts in case the vertical spacing provided by `\strut` isn't optimal for his/her purposes.

Comment: @Mico Good idea. I'll add some remark about this.

Comment: Could you perhaps comment why using packages `setspace` and `parskip` break the symmetry surrounding the strut in your solution?  If necessary I can open up a new question or update this original question.  I originally worked around this by using two different point sizes, but that's not the most elegant solution, so I would like to fix this properly, even if that means I shouldn't be using these packages.

Comment: @EngBIRD I think the best approach here would be for you to open a new question.