# Text position specified by coordinate, moving up and down with descenders/ascenders

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a variation on the spacing-with-descenders question seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254934/consistent-line-spacing-in-customized-titles) and elsewhere. I inherited some legacy TeX and don't actually know TeX, but I can run it fine, with this exception. The code combines input text with an image and spits out trading cards; almost none of it is *typeset* as text with automatic line spacing. Everything's position is specified in coordinates instead. The line relevant here generates the name at the top of the card:

```
\newcommand{\CardName}[1]{\node[text width = 5cm, align=left] at (3.54,8.605){\Large #1};}
```

If there's other relevant code elsewhere in my file i'm not sure what it is, sorry.

The name at the top of the card visibly wiggles up and down depending on ascenders/descenders:
[image]
[image: Name with a descender]
[image: Name with an ascender]

The solutions to this problem given in other questions depend on the text having its position/spacing set by the software relative to other text and so don't apply to my use case. How can I edit this code to specify the position of the text's *baseline* and put all the titles on the same height?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Try using `{\Large #1\strut}`

Comment: Is it related to the node baseline?

Comment: Probably, also setting `text depth` as option to the node, for example: `text depth=.25em`, could help.

Comment: @peter l a-ha, that did it! beautiful, I love a fix that only involves six extra characters. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed to change the end of the line to `{\Large #1\strut}` and that fixed it perfectly :) thank you to @Peter-Grill